# .htaccess Rewriting All Requests To A Subfolder Based on IP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to create a ban jail for my server and I want to rewrite all requests from an IP to a folder called "banned". From there, several PHP files will take care of the ban notification. I am having no issue with the scripts, but when I try to use the rewrite rules in my `.htaccess`, my browser simply warns me  that the page isn't redirecting properly. Here is my code

```
# Configure The Rules
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} ='<insert banned IP here>'">
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/banned
RewriteRule .* /banned
</If>
```

I have tried other solutions, but they either resulted in 500 errors, 400 errors, or a url filled with malformed requests such as "`example.com/*If/banned//var/www/html/*If/banned...`"

Please help.

Update: Using `curl -I: 'example.com'` produces the following result:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 10 Nov 2017 19:22:27 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location: https://example.com/banned/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be mindful of trailing slash that gets added after a directory by default using `mod_dir` module.

You can use this rule instead of your code:

```
# Configure The Rules
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} ='<insert banned IP here>'">
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/banned/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /banned/ [L]
</If>
```

Comment: No. Now its worse. It tries to redirect to the server root instead of "banned". Additionally, adding the trailing slashes to the original code causes a 500 error.

Comment: There is no redirection in this rule so it is happening outside this rule. Do you have other rules in this .htaccess or in `/banned/.htaccess`? If yes then show it here.

Comment: No. Its been sandboxed to one file. It will eventually have those rules written by the server itself via php. I wanted to test first to make sure they worked. The file is in the root directory so it works server-wide.

Comment: ok test using command line command `curl -I: 'http://example.com'` and paste it's output in question.

Comment: Turns out there was an error in the php file in "banned" that was processing the requests. It kept sending the client back to / thinking the ip wasn't banned. I fixed the issue and it works perfectly. Thanks for the help!